# "На e-mail" или "по e-mail"?

Tags: выбор-слов

На или по e-mail? Ждем ваших резюме на или по e-mail?

Answer (score 2):

Подставьте в это предложение слово "почта", и станет ясно, что здесь подойдёт только "по" (подразумевается "присланных по..." - каким способом). Вариант с "на" уместен в некоторых случаях, когда приводят или подразумевают конкретный адрес/ящик электронной почты ("*скинь файлы на мой имейл*" - куда? - предлог выражает направление). С глаголом "ждать"  предлог "на" (на чём, где?) при данном контексте не сочетается: получатель не будет сидеть *на (электронной) почте* и "ждать" там писем.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, ни так и ни так. Как посоветовал Alex_ander,  подставьте в это предложение слово "почта". "Ждем ваших резюме по почте"(?!) Разве это корректно?
Разве ждут по почте? "Ждем бабушку самолетом". Это так называемый телеграфный стиль. Им пользовались, когда цена телеграммы зависела от количества слов.   Тем более, неприемлем вариант "Ждем ваших резюме на почту" без указания адреса той почты, о которой идет речь. Почему бы не сказать: **"Посылайте  ваши резюме по e-mail" или "Посылайте ваши резюме на наш e-mail"?**